# Problem with AsyncTask (doInBackground method) when re-opening activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Recently I started using AsyncTask and I found some problems using it.

I have this `ListActivity` (CatalogActivity) and I used `AsyncTask` to reload it since it is some sort of tree logic. Each time I select an item in my list I do some calculations and show progress dialog in `doInBackground` method while in `onPostExecute` I reload the list and dismiss the progress. All works fine.

After im done (I reach the last level) I start another activity (LoginActivity). This new activity has "back" menu button that starts my previously mentioned list activity. It starts the activity, and when I hit the load part in `doInBackground` method I get this funky exception. The real interesting part is if I set breakpoint on my load method and step over all works fine !

What the heck am I missing?

Here is `doInBackground` method of my CatalogActivity (where the error happens):

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        catalogAdapter.mappingServicesCatalog.loadFromRml(new RIoConnectionManagerImpl(currentActivity.getApplicationContext()), params[0], null, 120000, 500000);
        if (catalogAdapter.urlMapping.size() == 0)
        {
            catalogAdapter.urlMapping.add(params[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (catalogAdapter.urlMapping.get(catalogAdapter.urlMapping.size() - 1) != params[0])
            {
                catalogAdapter.urlMapping.add(params[0]);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Here are LogCat records:

```
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity$CatalogAdapter.access$1(CatalogActivity.java:35)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity$LoadRMLCatalog.doInBackground(CatalogActivity.java:197)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity$LoadRMLCatalog.doInBackground(CatalogActivity.java:1)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-20 11:38:21.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22789):     ... 4 more
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789): Activity si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47f532a0 that was originally added here
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47f532a0 that was originally added here
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity.loadRMLCatalog(CatalogActivity.java:135)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity$CatalogAdapter.Initialize(CatalogActivity.java:60)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity$CatalogAdapter.<init>(CatalogActivity.java:45)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity.onCreate(CatalogActivity.java:119)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
06-20 11:38:44.086: ERROR/WindowManager(22789):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 11:49:00.402: ERROR/WifiManager(22835): showApDialog
06-20 11:49:04.699: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(2475): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
06-20 11:49:07.511: ERROR/WifiManager(22835): showApDialog
06-20 11:49:14.648: ERROR/WifiManager(22835): showApDialog
06-20 11:49:23.109: ERROR/libnetutils(2475): dhcp start cmd 11 : [dhcpcd:-ABK] 
06-20 11:49:23.597: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(2475): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
06-20 11:49:23.965: ERROR/gps_BRCM(2475): BrcmLbs_sync() return error.
```

Comment: Need line numbers in your code excerpt, in order to line up with the NPE stacktrace: si.realis.rmap.android.CatalogActivity$CatalogAdapter.access$1(CatalogActivity.java:35)  -- which line in your snippet is line 35?  The `.access$1()` implies that it's requesting a private member using a synthetic accessor method, and that member appears to be null.  You said it "starts" the previous activity, but why not just let the BACK key do its thing, and finish the top activity, resuming the previous activity?

Comment: you are right. A typical noob mistake. I have activity and an adapter. In adapter constructor i had some code that started this async task. When i debugged the adapter synchronised, but when in runtime there was error. I removed the code from adapters constructor in an method and it works. Thank you for your time ! Sloppy work on my side ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by fixing my code (sloppy work)